# php for-loop never executed

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a stupid problem which occurs when running this script.  Why is the body of the for-loop never executed?

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$i=0.0;
$j=1.0;
$max=3000;

for ($z=0; $z==$max;  $z++) {
  $i += (1.0/$max);
  $j -= (1.0/$max);

  echo "j=$j - i= $i <br>";
  if( ($z % 100) == 0){

      echo "j=$j  ¦ i= $i <br>";
  };
};

?>
```

EDIT: as you see it is possible to learn stupidity ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will never enter.

```
for ($z=0; $z==$max;  $z++)
```

`z` cannot be `==` to `$max`

---

Try this instead:

```
for ($z=0; $z<=$max;  $z++)
```

Comment: @kjy112 look at the revision history.

Comment: must have been editing at the same time or something.  i didn't mean to change the content of your answer but merely the format of the "code" i apologize if you feel offended.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($z=0; $z==$max;  $z++)
```

You want $z <= $max.

The middle of a for loop is the conditional statement and if it evaluates to false it doesn't execute.

That loop is essentially the same as:

```
$z = 0;
while($z == $max){
     // Do Stuff
     $z++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

> ```
> for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
>     statement
> ```
>
> The first expression (expr1) is evaluated (executed) once unconditionally at the beginning of the loop.
>
> In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.
>
> At the end of each iteration, expr3 is evaluated (executed).

You might want to put `$z<=$max` there.

Comment: Actually, it will never run, not even once.  `expr2` is FALSE before the 1st iteration, so nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I misread "The first expression (...) is evaluated (...) unconditionally" as "The first loop will be executed unconditionally...". My bad. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop will be ran only if the second statement is true in your case `$z == $max`. That is definitely not true, because you already had defined that the value of **$z** is **0** and $max is 3000. It's like you had entered `for($z=0;0 == 3000;$z++){}`